# @Query doesn't work if I select more than 1 column

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have a query like below that doesn't work. 
It throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` 
(sorry I can't post the whole stacktrace as it is in my workstation (remote))
This started to be an issue when I upgraded from Spring Boot `1.5.2.RELEASE` to `1.5.22.RELEASE`

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(value = "SELECT q.id as someId, q.name as someName from Quote q where q.id in (:quoteIds)")
List<Tuple> selectSomeThings(@Param("quoteIds") List<Long> quoteIds)
```

Now when I try to just select 1 column like so,

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(value = "SELECT q.id as someId from Quote q where q.id in (:quoteIds)")
List<Tuple> selectSomeThings(@Param("quoteIds") List<Long> quoteIds)
```

or

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(value = "SELECT q.name as someName from Quote q where q.id in (:quoteIds)")
List<Tuple> selectSomeThings(@Param("quoteIds") List<Long> quoteIds)
```

it works. Just doesn't work when I select 2 at the same time.

Comment: Without the full stacktrace I can only guess. Please add as much of the stacktrace as you can. Why don't you try to reproduce the exception locally?

Comment: I understand. Let me reproduce it locally and give further context. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to return a Bean instance from the repository methode.

Example here:

```
    @Query("SELECT " +
           "    new com.path.to.Tuple(v.id, v.name) " +
           "FROM " +
           "    Quote v where v.id in (:quoteIds) ")
    List<Tuple> find(@Param("quoteIds") List<Long> quoteIds);
```